# Where is Stack Overflow heading now?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am a user not nearly long enough to be judging how it was in "good old days", but I somehow always thought SO was a site for people to answer any questions related to programming computers. And programming computers comes with knowledge (and so - questions) about programming languages, algorithms, data structures, best programming practices, hardware knowledge, operating systems knowledge and many more.

Now I find myself often confused, both when I want to ask a question or when I read other questions: is Stack Overflow a suitable site for this question?

It happens that somebody asks about an algorithm and uses pseudocode - they are usually sent to Computer Science Stack Exchange or (worse) TCS SE. Somebody asks about complexity and uses pseudocode - same as above. Then on TCS if you ask about something not at so-called *research level*, you'll be sent to CS Stack Exchange. There are more examples, and I am pretty sure all of us noticed.

As there are many specialized Stack Exchange sites now, including:

- Programmers,
- Theoretical Computer Science,
- Computer Science,
- Super User,

where is the place for Stack Overflow now? I would like everyone reading this to understand - I am not a hater here, I am trying to understand the goal of every site. If general algorithm- or data structure-related questions should go to CS, *research-level* (I am sure there are more people that get confused about this) questions should go to TCS (but a question about Quantum Computing is not abstract enough as far as I know), programming practice questions should be asked at Programmers SE and operating-system stuff goes to Super User (or AskUbuntu or some else, I guess), what kind of questions should be asked here?

Sometimes I have a question related to programming, but I am not sure if it is technology-related-enough to be asked on SO, or should it be in CS or even TCS? What are the guidelines now? And what if some other sites emerge, like Java Stack Exchange - where will Stack Overflow go then?

Comment: Related: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: I failed to find something like this. Will read it soon, thank you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, at least not of the linked question. I share the sentiment.

Answer (score 9):

The way I think of it is, your starting point for code/programming related questions is Stack Overflow. Your question fits in Stack Overflow if you have specific question about some specific code, or an issue using a framework, problem with your CSS code not aligning up (etc etc), and the question is answerable without any level of the opinion being able to be contested.
i.e. The answer should "work" to resolve the question.

While all Stack sites require an *answerable question* to some degree, I see SO as retaining a more tight handle on this aspect. And while answers may differ in their *approach or code used*, essentially your question should be able to be answered quite easily without any thought about *opinion*.

Then, if your question scope moves slightly towards having any level of "how to" or "best way" then it's not for Stack Overflow.
It may not be for another site either, but Programmers, for example, allows a slight element of "Is A or B better for X".
Again, all sites still need an *answerable* question, and not open up a debate in answers because it is entirely opinionated.

---

Descriptions from all site Tour pages:

**Stack Overflow**
Is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. [snip] working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about **programming**.

**Programmers**
Is a question and answer site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on **conceptual** questions about software development. [snip] working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about **software development**.

**Server Fault**
Is a question and answer site for professional system and network administrators. [snip] working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about **professional server, networking,** or related **infrastructure administration**.

**Super User**
Is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. [snip] working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about **computer software or hardware**.

**Webmasters**
Is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast webmasters. [snip] working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the **operation of websites**.

---

I think there is some overlap, for example *a question* may be fine on both Stack Overflow and Webmasters, however not all questions suited to one are also suited to the other.

Same with the other sites. I think it's the *potentially acceptable overflow* which confuses us, eg one question can fit a few sites.
But again, each site does have a plethora of questions which do only suit the one site and are not suited to the other sites.

Have a look on the main questions page on some of the sites you mentioned. You will think "I see why that wouldn't work on Stack Overflow" and vice versa.

Comment: I think it is not very good idea to be so strict about opinions. Some opinion based answers can still be useful

Comment: @giorgim: sure, they can go to opinionated sites, like software recommendation.

Comment: @lpapp:not necessarily. Someone who has no idea about how to proceed, can find someone else's - even - opinion, helpful

Comment: @giorgim No one is saying that opinions aren't helpful. But SO is not the place for them, because we want the site focused on specific programming issues, not on matters of opinion. If you have an opinion based question, then try another site in SE. If one doesn't exist, then find some forums or ask people via social media.

Comment: And then there's Ubuntu, Unix & Linux, Apple, Web Applications, …  It was bad enough when Stack Overflow became "the trilogy" (Stack Overflow, SuperUser, ServerFault); it hasn't gotten any easier since.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I think that only one that wouldn't have to exist is the Ubuntu one. But they pay for it, so I don't believe in a merge with Unix & Linux. I believe this confusion only happens if you don't really know the websites. For most part they are quite straight forward.